# Using gzip to Optimize Upload to Drive using API v3 Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api

I'm sorry, I'm quite new to Drive API.

I understand from Google's post in [Performance Tips](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/performance) that recommends to gzip before uploading to Google Drive. However, I wasn't able to find a way to implement gzip using Python 3 Drive API v3 to compress files before uploading and decompress it after uploaded.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think it would help to check the tutorials online for Python implementation. On Python's [gzip — Support for gzip files](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html), you can read some of their code snippets:

**Example of how to read a compressed file:**

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('file.txt.gz', 'rb') as f:
file_content = f.read()
```

**Example of how to GZIP compress an existing file:**

```
import gzip
import shutil
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f_in, gzip.open('file.txt.gz', 'wb') as f_out:
shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```